# Unity how to improve your 3dDgame preformance for mobile devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have build a pinball game in unity 3d for android and for some low mobile devices it is running slowly. I was thinking about hiring a unity expert to lighten up the code so it would run better on all devices.

But I wonder if this is possible. Can you make a game preform better by changing the code? I have to add this was my first unity project and it's very messy.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, there are plenty of ways that changes to code could yield significant increases in performance, depending on how you're currently doing things.

One of them is [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling) when dealing with frequent creation/destruction of objects, another is [caching component references](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/129719/just-need-some-clarification-regarding-component-v.html) when they are used often every frame. And if you're still using `OnGui` for your interface, [probably avoid it](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/551274/why-is-ongui-called-significantly-more-than-update.html) in favour of the new (as of 4.6) GUI system. But you haven't included your code in your question, so I can't give a definite solution for optimizing your code.

Chances are though, not all of your code is problematic, just key scripts. My suggestion is to take a look at the [Unity Profiler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to determine which areas in your code are slowing down your game the most, then take steps to try reducing the execution time. You should also take into consideration non-code problems (eg. With lighting, geometry, materials, textures). Take a look at the [guide Unity provides](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html) for ideas on how to address those

If you're still having problems, then you can bring that specific code to StackOverflow and see if it can be further improved. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.